# Can't register any component in Delphi 11

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a problem with Delphi 11. I can't register any of my components, I get the attached error when i right click on the package and select Install

```
unit MyNewComponent;

interface

uses
 System.Classes,
 FMX.Objects;

type
  TMyComp = class(TShape)
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('BRTesting', [TMyComp]);
end;
end.
```

[image: Delphi error when registering component]

There is allready registered a bug at embarcadero (https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-36334) but I was hoping that I could get help here, because I fear that embarcadero is not going to fix this in the near future. And maybe they have changed something in the way we now have to register own components?

Comment: No problems creating a package, adding a FM component using the wizards and installing here. Only differences compared to what you posted are more units in the uses (`System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Objects;`) and the type definition includes the sections (private, protected etc).  Neither of those differences would lead to the error you are seeing.

Comment: Does the error also appear for components based on a VCL component?

Comment: I don't know if it also appear on VCL components.
But when I uninstall my Devart UniDac package it works in my test app :(

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and solution was uninstall Devart Unidac, restart delphi, install new components and finay

Answer (score 0):

We were also faced with this problem. It actually stems from the DevArt components. But it is not necessary to uninstall the components. It is enough to deactivate them and restart Delphi.

After the installation, the DevArt components can be reactivated without any problems.

Comment: We have already worked on this problem, please write to our support for a quick solution.